# Asset allocation and IRA

Tags: united-states, ira, asset-allocation

I have to take a required minimum distribution from my IRAs every year.  And I pay taxes on it at a marginal rate of 24%.  I also have assets in a non-IRA investment account.

I do make some charitable contributions out of my IRAs, but most of the distributions will be taxed.

Question:  When I reallocate my investments, should I treat my IRA assets as being only 76% of the value shown on my investment statement, since I will only be able to enjoy 76% of their value? I realize that I am assuming that I will be spending all my assets, and that the answer may be different if they pass to my beneficiaries.